# Is there a way to specify which IAuthProvider to use for authentication on a particular Service class?

Tags: authentication, jwt, servicestack, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two services within the same project:

```
    [Authenticate]
    public class OnlyDoesBasicAuth : Service
    {   
    }

    [Authenticate]
    public class OnlyDoesJwtAuth : Service
    {
    }

    //AppHost
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new BasicAuthProvider(AppSettings),
                    new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                }
            )
        {
            HtmlRedirect = null
        });
    }
```

The way this is set up, I can get into **both** services using Basic Authentication or with a valid Bearer token.  I'd prefer to have it so that only one service can do one means of authentication.  Is there a way to specify with provider to use on authentication?

I'm at a loss on how to approach this.  I was thinking that maybe there was a way via global request filter or something to that effect, but maybe that's not the way to go.  I could split the project into two projects, which will definitely work, but it's not the way I want to approach it.

**I'm just looking for a way for the OnlyDoesBasicAuth to only use the BasicAuthProvider on authentication and OnlyDoesJwtAuth to only use the JwtAuthProvider within the same project.  Any and all suggestions will be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically once you're authenticated using any of the Auth Providers you're considered as an Authenticated User everywhere in ServiceStack.

You can restrict access so that a Service needs to be Authenticated with by specifying the AuthProvider name in the `[Authenticate]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Authenticate(BasicAuthProvider.Name)]
public class OnlyDoesBasicAuth : Service
{   
}

[Authenticate(JwtAuthProvider.Name)]
public class OnlyDoesJwtAuth : Service
{
}
```

Alternatively you can validate within your Service that they need to be authenticated with a specific Auth Provider, e.g:

```
if (SessionAs<AuthUserSession>().AuthProvider != JwtAuthProvider.Name)
   throw HttpError.Forbidden("JWT Required");
```